# Getting the last MB of a file with cURL

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to get the last 1MB of data of a file with cURL? I know I can get the first MB, but I need the last one.

Comment: Read the entire file and take the last 1MB.

Comment: Yeah but the idea is to avoid to read all the file.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  That seems a bit wasteful, depending on how large the file is.  Perhaps by adding a [range header](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.35) to the request, you can get the last 1MB of data.

Comment: @TimCooper: Can you do that with Curl?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It appears so: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Range: bytes ...'));`

Comment: @TimCooper: Well there you go then.  How about posting an answer?

Comment: @TimCooper thanks! You can post it as response.

Comment: Not all servers respect range header. Without it, you will need to get the entire file in order to figure what data is the last megabyte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by specifying an HTTP Range header in your request:

```
// $curl = curl_init(...);
$lower = $size - 1024 * 1024;
$upper = $size;
url_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Range: bytes=$lower-$upper"));
```

Note: you need to make sure that the server you are requesting the data from allows this.  Make a `HEAD` request, and check for the `Accept-Ranges` header.

Here is an example that you should be able to tweak to fit your needs:

```
// Make HEAD request
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($curl);

preg_match('/^Content-Length: (\d+)/m', $data, $matches);
$size = (int) $matches[1];
$lower = $size - 1024 * 1024;

// Get last MB of data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Range: bytes=$lower-$size"));

$data = curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but you can do it by specifying only the upper range:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Get the last 100 bytes and echo the results
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Range: bytes=-100"));
echo htmlentities(curl_exec($ch)) . "<br /><br />";

// Get the last 200 bytes and echo the results
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Range: bytes=-200"));
echo htmlentities(curl_exec($ch));
```

This returns:

```
100 bytes: <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p> </div> </body> </html> 

200 bytes: ou may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p> <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p> </div> </body> </html>
```

From [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35):

> By its choice of last-byte-pos, a client can limit the number of bytes retrieved without knowing the size of the entity.