# Can't read force-download file with CURL?

Tags: php, image, curl

i'm trying to read a part of one file. But the file hosting server return as force-download at header.

i can use fopen , fread to read a part of file.

```
$f = fopen('http://www.hdwallpapers.org/download/beautiful-red-tree-scene-1280x800.jpg','r');
$response = fread($f, 3); echo $response.'<br>';
echo $response;exit();
```

but when i switch to use CURL

```
$curl = curl_init('http://www.hdwallpapers.org/download/beautiful-red-tree-scene-1280x800.jpg');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, "0-2");
$response = curl_exec($curl);echo $response.'<br>';
```

it's return nothing.

Here is file header:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=beautiful-red-tree-scene-1280x800.jpg
Content-Length:427882
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/force-download
Date:Sat, 26 Oct 2013 04:11:25 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=75
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
```

So, how to read a part of force-download file with CURL?

Comment: twice? what are you talking about?

Comment: did you see this Q/A link ?




[getting-the-last-mb-of-a-file-with-curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823455/getting-the-last-mb-of-a-file-with-curl)

Comment: @M2sh won't work. did you tried my code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it using following code

```
function grab_image($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: i don't wanna use fopen. can use it with curl only? and your code, is return nothing

Comment: As i know you need to use fopen here.I updated my code .try it

Comment: i don't wanna save/download a file. i only want to read a small part of it with CURL. You can see curlopt_range here. i can easy do it with fopen+fread, but i could not with curl and the file with force-download header

Answer (score 0):

You just want to read the file? or force a download? anyways.. here is how to read it.

```
 $link = 'http://www.hdwallpapers.org/download/beautiful-red-tree-scene-1280x800.jpg';
 $curl = curl_init($link);

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 //curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, "0-2");

 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 $data = base64_encode ($response);

 echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,{$data}'>";
```

Comment: i wanna to read small part of a file. and your code is doesn't work. this is force -download file. you can not simple read small part of it before complete download it

Comment: This code does not download the image initially.. it reads it in to <img>, did you even try it out? Also please try clarify a bit better on the meaning of "read small part". if you just want to read half of it than you are better of putting the image data in a gd function.

Comment: What do you mean its not returning anything? maybe something you are doing wrong.... here is a link that show the image http://hexcoderz.net/temp/test.php

Comment: you do not unserstand? you download whole file. i need to read small part of it only. i can download whole file if i increased timeout higher. my location is far from server, so i need more 10 seconds to complete download a file. that is why timeout = 5 return nothing, please run my fopen / fread code to see what will return, that's what i supose to need

Comment: In that case what @M2sh stated should be what you are looking for.

Comment: �� ~> small 3 bytes , read by fopen / fread. if you use CURL in this case, it will returned whole file. @M2sh example won't work in this case, because server return force-download file